# Let $p$ be a prime that decomposes completely in $O_K$. Show that $\#\text{Hom}(O_K, \mathbb{F}_p)=n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field of degree $n$. We say a prime $p$ decomposes completely in $O_K$ if $pO_K = \mathfrak{p}_1...\mathfrak{p}_n$ for some prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}_i$. I want to show that if $p$ is a prime that decomposes completely then $\#\text{Hom}(O_K, \mathbb{F}_p)=n$ but I don't really know how to attack this problem. I feel like I should be using that $O_K$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-module or that the degree of the extension is n, but I don't really know how.

Comment: Rene's answer is, of course, good. I tried to split the logic into smaller steps.

Comment: Do you require that $\mathfrak{p}_i \neq \mathfrak{p}_j$ when $i \neq j$? (i.e. that none of the primes over $p$ are ramified)

Comment: @Hurkyl I'm prepared to be wrong but the phrase "splits completely" carries the implication that there is no ramification. Possibly the same also applies  "decomposes completely" - may be a different translation?

Comment: @Hurkyl $\mathfrak{p}_i \neq \mathfrak{p}_j$ when $i \neq j$. I looked up "decomposes completely" in google and thought that was the correct translation. Sorry.

Answer (score 5):

Here are a few off the cuff comments that may help you on your way. First under any map $\mathcal{O}_K \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_p$, the set $p\mathcal{O}_K$ is sent to zero. So look at $\mathcal{O}_K/p\mathcal{O}_K$. This is isomorphic to $$\prod \mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}_i.$$ Maybe this is a good point for me to stop.

Comment: So you are saying that $\prod \mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}_i \cong \mathbb{F}_p$? Because that doesn't seem to be true, I know that $p\mathcal{O}_K \subset Ker(\sigma)$ for a homomorphism $\sigma$ but I don't know about the other direction. Also, $\mathbb{F}_p$ has size $p$ but  $\prod \mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}_i$ is a product of integers. So what do you mean by look at $\mathcal{O}_K / p\mathcal{O}_K$?

Comment: @McNuggets it will be isomorphic to a product of finite fields, not to $\mathbb F_p$. The question reduces to calculating the number of maps from a product of finite fields to $\mathbb F_p$.

Answer (score 4):

Hints/roadmap:

- So we have a homomorphism $f$ of rings from $O_K$ to the field $\Bbb{F}_p$. Can you show that $f$ is necessarily surjective?
- The previous bullet implies that $O_K/\operatorname{ker}(f)\simeq\Bbb{F}_p$. Do you recall what we can say about an ideal $I$ of a commutative ring $R$, when the quotient ring $R/I$ is an integral domain?
- Why does the choice of $\operatorname{ker}(f)$ determine $f$ uniquely in this case? Why do different choices for the kernel give rise to different homomorphisms.